# Powershell Array: HOWTO Dedup Output

Tags: arrays, powershell, duplicates

When I run this parser script on my contacts.xml, which shows one line per user, I get multiple instances of the same data. I only want a single entry for the same data. How do I dedup the data before it writes to the CSV?

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999682/powershell-parsing-a-text-file
$input = Get-Content $env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\contacts.xml\Downloads\contacts.xml
$array = @()
$input | % {
    $writeobj = $false
    $obj = New-Object System.Object
    if ($_ -match 'email*') {
        $Email = ($_ -split ':')[1]
    }
    if ($_ -match 'FN*') {
        $NAME = ($_ -split ':')[1]
        $writeobj = $true
    }
    if ($writeobj) {
        $obj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Email -Value $Email
        $obj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $NAME
        $array += $obj
    }
    Write-Host $Name, $email
}
$array | Export-Csv -Path C:\scripts\reports\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I expect this to produce single entries but I get duplicates (and they don't line up right either). 
(And yes I checked the XML file for single entries)

Comment: the `$Input` var name is one of the automatic $Var names ... don't _ever_ use it. [*grin*]

Comment: Why don't you cast the content to [xml] and inspect the properties/values?

Comment: `$input` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0#input) and shouldn't be re-purposed like that. Use a different variable name.

Comment: @PatrickBurwell - that variable - `$Input` is an automatic variable and should not be used unless you have a need for what it is designed for. otherwise, you can find that your data is doing **_strange things_** ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-3.0) the unique objects.

```
$array |
    Select-Object -Property * -Unique |
    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\scripts\reports\test.csv' -NoType
```

As a side note, you may want to avoid appending to an array in a loop, as that is bound to perform poorly. Just pipe your `ForEach-Object` loop directly into `Export-Csv`.

Comment: @PatrickBurwell Try `Get-Content ... | % {...} | Select-Object ... | Export-Csv ...`.

Comment: Okay, I'm getting a Carriage Return at the top of the Email column that rows everything off...(I changed the emails)
Name Email 
Scott SPACE 
Scott Scott@Christian.com 
Radhika Scott@Christian.com 
Radhika radhika@consultinginc.com

Comment: If you have a carriage return somewhere in your data that is messing up your formatting you can remove it via `-replace '\r'`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
I REVERSED the $obj Add-Member variables *that fixed the order) and added another "**$writeobj = $true**" line to the FN match, and VOILÀ no more dupes.
Is that weird or what?

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999682/powershell-parsing-a-text-file
$input = Get-Content $env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\contacts.xml $array =
@() $input | % {
    $writeobj = $false
    $obj = New-Object System.Object
    If ($_ -match 'email') {
        $Email = ($_ -split ':')[1]
        $writeobj = $true
    }
    If ($_ -match 'FN') {
        $NAME = ($_ -split ':')[1]
        $writeobj = $true # <-- right here
    }
    If ($writeobj){
        $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Email -value **$NAME**
        $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value **$Email**
        $array += $obj
    }
    Write-Host $Name, $email } $array | Export-Csv -path C:\scripts\reports\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```